# what is Linux global scheduling policy?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, scheduling

I am learning operating systems. I have a doubt. For example if scheduling policy for some set of process(set 1) is `SCHED_RR` and scheduling policy for some other set of processes(set 2) is `SCHED_FIFO` .

Now when kernel has to pick some process from these 2 sets, which scheduling policy does Linux uses?

Is it possible to change that policy? If so how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man sched`

> Conceptually, the scheduler maintains a list of  runnable  threads 
>   for    each possible sched_priority value.  In order to determine
>   which thread    runs next, the scheduler looks for the nonempty list
>   with  the  highest    static priority and selects the thread at the
>   head of this list.
>
> A  thread's scheduling policy determines where it will be inserted
>   into    the list of threads with equal static priority and  how  it 
>   will  move    inside this list.

although there is one more real-time policy, where the priority is not (at all?) significant

> In order to fulfil the guarantees that are made when a thread is
>   admit‐    ted  to the SCHED_DEADLINE policy, SCHED_DEADLINE threads
>   are the high‐    est  priority  (user  controllable)  threads  in  the
>   system;  if  any    SCHED_DEADLINE thread is runnable, it will preempt
>   any thread scheduled    under one of the other policies.